# Oracle - clean LOB files - recovering disk space

Tags: oracle

I have a friend who has a website and asked me for help.
I often use MySQL databases but never Oracle databases.
And unfortunately he has an Oracle database, so I can't find a solution.

The available disk space is slowly decreasing... I delete a lot of lines from the table but that doesn't solve his problem.
The database continues to take up disk space slowly.

I read that LOB files do not return disk space, even if you delete data.

- How can I reorganize LOB files easily with a simple request?
- (or/and) How can I recover disk space on Oracle?

```
SELECT DISTINCT VERSION FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
```

```
12.1.0.1.0
```

Comment: never done it myself but https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/alter-table-shrink-space-online is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BLOB` column exists within the table blocks along with data even after deletion.  It is only **marked as unused**.  You can use the following command to free up space from the `BLOB` table:

```
ALTER TABLE <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> MODIFY
    LOB <LOB_COLUMN_NAME>
( SHRINK SPACE );
```

Now, Table must have released some space and it is now available to be used within the tablespace.

Further, you can just alter the data file and reduce the size of the data file accordingly to free up space from Disk. (Note: Space allocated to the data file will not be automatically reduced. It must be done manually)

Cheers!!

Comment: Oh, thank you, that seems to be what I need. However, I still have some questions to complete for myself and future StackOverFlow users.

- There is no risk of losing data with this request?

Comment: I need to use `SELECT  TABLESPACE_NAME Tablename, FILE_NAME Filename, BYTES/1024/1024 SizeMB, MAXBYTES/1024/1024 MaximumSizeMB, AUTOEXTENSIBLE AutoExtensible from SYS.DBA_DATA_FILES ORDER BY Tablename, Filename` as query to know the `<LOB_COLUMN_NAME>` ?

Comment: What changes with: `alter table <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> enable row movement;    alter table  <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> shrink space cascade; 
   alter table  <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> disable row movement;`

Comment: For LOB you need what is given in answer. And what you mentioned in the comments are called vaccum cleaning and is needed to reclaim the space from table which will release the block below HWM and set new HWM

Comment: a handy link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/alter-table-shrink-space-online - in case of SecureFile LOBs and existance of materialized views, things get more complex